# Calculating the average time in each node when 'hopping' through a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm dealing with a graph that looks like this:

[image]

The nodes are numbers from 0 to 9, and the vertices are bi-directional. Starting from node 0, a figure 'hops' to one of other nodes connected to it, each with equal probability. I'd like to compute the expected value and standard deviation of the cumulative sum $S$ of the numbers hopped through, modulo 10 - let's call the quantity $\left<S\right>_{10}$ - after a given number of hops $T$, starting from node $0$.

Since the cumulative sum $S$ is taken modulo 10, its possible values are the same as the nodes of the original graph. The new graph under this operation I determined to look like this:

[image]

How would one, given a starting node and number of hops $T$, determine the expected number of times each node is visited?

I'll share below what I've done so far. I've implemented a 'brute force' method in Python which simply counts all the nodes the figure could be at at each hop.

```
import numpy as np

graph = {0 : [4,6],
        1 : [6,8],
        2 : [7,9],
        3 : [4,8],
        4 : [3,9,0],
        5 : [],
        6 : [1,7,0],
        7 : [2,6],
        8 : [1,3],
        9 : [2,4],
        }

def graph_cumsum_modulo(graph, mod):
    graph_mod = {}
    for node in range(10):
        graph_mod[node] = map(lambda x: (node + x) % mod, graph[node])
    return graph_mod

# Given a list of possible nodes, return a list of possible nodes after one hop in the graph
def get_new_possibilities(possibilities, graph):
    new_possibilities = []
    for possibility in possibilities:
        new_possibilities += graph[possibility]     # Only works when mod = 10
    return new_possibilities

def get_expected_times_visited(T, graph):
    possibilities = [0]     # Starting point of list of possible nodes
    expected_times_visited = np.zeros(10)
    expected_times_visited[0] += 1.0
    for _ in range(T):
        possibilities = get_new_possibilities(possibilities, graph)
        for node in range(10):
            expected_times_visited[node] += possibilities.count(node) / float(len(possibilities))
    return expected_times_visited

mod = 10
graph10 = graph_cumsum_modulo(graph,mod)
print(graph10)

T = 10      # Number of steps
expected_times_visited = get_expected_times_visited(T, graph10)

expected_S_mod_10 = np.average(range(10), weights=expected_times_visited)
print("The expected value of S modulo 10 is %.10f" % expected_S_mod_10)

variance_S_mod_10 = np.average((range(10)-expected_S_mod_10)**2, weights=expected_times_visited)
std_S_mod_10 = np.sqrt(variance_S_mod_10)
print("The standard deviation of S modulo 10 is %.10f" % std_S_mod_10)
```

This prints the following output:

```
The expected value of S modulo 10 is 4.5454545455
The standard deviation of S modulo 10 is 3.0302593501
```

which seems about right by comparison with a Monte Carlo simulation. The problem is that if I increase `T` from `10` to say, `100`, the code takes prohibitively long to run (it actually just exits with null). However, I eventually need to solve the problem for larger values of `T`.

Is there a smarter, perhaps recursive, way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). The states are pairs consisting of the current node and the current sum modulo $10$; there are $10^2=100$ of them. The initial distribution has probability $1$ in the state at node $0$ with sum $0$. You could diagonalise the transition matrix to express the probabilities in terms of its spectral decomposition, but since you're using code anyway, you can just apply the transition matrix to the initial state $T$ times to get the probabilities after $T$ steps. Since the transition matrix is sparse, with about $2$ transitions per state, this requires only about $2\cdot100\cdot T$ operations.